# Related calendar custom fields from an event

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is is possible to get custom field data of a calendar from a related event? Basically I want to be able to assign colors to calendars as a custom field, and then within the `{events}` variable pair set the background color of an event based on which calendar it belongs to. So something like:

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="year-month-01" ... }

  {display_each_day}

    {date format="%J"}        

    {events}

      <article style="background-color: #{calendar_color};">
        <h1>{event_title}</h1>
      </article>

    {/events}

  {/display_each_day}

{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

The above code will only output a blank string for the `{calendar_color}` custom field (I assume this is because the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag by default will output multiple calendars).

So basically I'm just looking for a way to create a reverse relationship from the event to the calendar based on the relationship that is already setup between calendars and events with Solspace Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can call relationships inside calendar events.
You need to follow the correct syntax just as if this were a regular calendar:entries tag.
ref http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html

Comment: Does this actually work for you, @pseudoclass? I'm assuming your {calendar_color} is a custom field in your Calendar channel. And events are related to a Calendar, but not through an EE relationship... so what syntax do you use to output {calendar_color} from within an {exp:calendar:cal} or {exp:calendar:events} tag?